# Have Entity Framework code first database in MVC project. Added console project to solution but it cannot connect to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC project in which I used Entity Framework code first approach to create my database. The database exists and I can query it from my MVC project without any issues.

Now, I added a console project to the solution. Within this console project I added a reference to my MVC project, added Entity Framework NuGet package and added the connection string from web.config (in the MVC project) into app.config (in the console project).

The connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TradeManagerContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=TradeManagerDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|TradeManagerDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I verified that this is the connection string being used in the console app with this debugging code:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString=" + db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

When my console app attempts to query the database:

```
var result = db.Trades.Where(c => c.Ticker == "AAPL");
```

That line throws an exception with message:

> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\RED\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\TradeManager\Console\bin\Debug\TradeManagerDB.mdf' as
>   database 'TradeManagerDB'.

Any ideas on what this exception means and how I can resolve it?

Here is the full stack trace:

> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__2()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

Comment: I would highly recommend to make a center location from which you communicate with the DB, this will make your code clean. Keep the DB communication in the MVC and make some static helper classes to call the DB

Comment: Yes, I add a class library project where I implement the repository and unit of work patterns to keep code clean. Just didn't get to it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to load the file TradeManagerDB from the App_Data folder. You need to use a different syntax to load it from elsewhere.

Comment: I see. I removed the `AttachDbFilename=` portion of the connection string and it is working now. Thanks for the insight.